# How denoise infrared images ? (SST, sea surface temperature)

Tags: cloud, gradient

I'm working on a project in images processing that should denoise satellite image (SST , sea surface temperature) from the cloud cover and missing data. this is a very complex and important task, because the presence of cloud contamination and missing data in the input image can have serious effects on the results of any gradient approach.

If anyone could help me out, or give me a hint, I really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is applicable for you, but one possibility could be to use [HDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_dynamic_range_imaging).
You could also try a blur effect, but this could destruct the quality of your image.